# How would I utilize OpenMDAO to interface with SysML?

Tags: python, openmdao

From my current and very basic understanding, users need to define their entire model using add_input,add_output,add_design_var,etc... in Python if they want to run analysis/optimization in OpenMDAO.

There is no GUI interface, so is there an easier way to create models or to send SysML to OpenMDAO for optimization or would a user have to define their model twice, once in SysML and once in Python?

Answer (score 0):

The OpenMDAO GUI was removed as of version 1, and there are no current plans to re-introduce it into version 2.

There isn't any current links between sysml tools and OpenMDAO. You could certainly write something that would read a sysml file and build the appropriate OpenMDAO model from it, but nothing like that exists currently.

The major hurdle with a system like this is how you keep the two systems (sysml and OpenMDAO) in sync. If you generate the model from a sysml tool, then modify it by hand later, how do those updates get fed back into the OpenMDAO model.

I think the idea would work as long as it was uni-directional. sysml -> OpenMDAO.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you help clarify some things about the tool? I am not a systems engineer by any means (I'm just setting up tools for them). What is meant by "analysis and optimization"?


Say I give OpenMDAO a plane wing, is it supposed to auto-magically find the absolute best solution for plane wing shape using libraries/solvers that are predefined for particular problems?

Comment: I would say you could find answers here: http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/basic_guide/index.html

Comment: Writing something to translate between SysML and OpenMDAO models seems extremely complicated. I was thinking of maybe just writing plugins for Magic Draw case by case which solve very particular optimization problems. By doing that however, I would't really be utilizing the power of OpenMDAO. 

Could you explain to a non systems engineer what exactly I'd be missing out on if I didn't went with this approach besides the fact that I would have to code every optimization problem explicitly?